# Adding element to mapping (solidity) is not working, even if the method is actually called in the transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, mapping

I'm currently working (as a begineer) at a project involving ethereum blockchain and solidity.

In my contract I have a mapping with addresses as key and the value of an array of a FileDetails structure. Anyway when I try to add elements to the array and to the mapping it doesn't get updated even if the method is correctly called (see the transaction details below). I am currently using a React application with the truffle suite. (Ganache for running a test blockchain).

I have the following contract:

```
contract Files {
    struct FileDetails {
        string fileHash; // The IPFS file hash
        string fileName; // The file name
        string transactionDate; // The date in which file infos was stored
        string fileExtension; // The type of file (its extension)
    }

    mapping(address => FileDetails[]) filesList;

    function addFile(string memory fileHash, string memory fileName, string memory fileType, string memory date) public {
        FileDetails memory fileDetail = FileDetails({
            fileHash: fileHash,
            fileName: fileName,
            fileExtension: fileType,
            transactionDate: date
        });
        filesList[msg.sender].push(fileDetail);
    }
}
```

Now I'm calling the function `addFile(...)` from javascript with the following:

```
await contract.methods.addFile("aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd").send({ from: accounts[0] });
```

As you can see I put into parameters random strings just for testing.

Now, when I call it I actually get something:
[image]

The contract is called and even the function with parameters is correctly called in the transaction.

Beside that, I don't get any updates in the mapping structure that I can see in the contract from Ganache (0 items):
[image]

I don't know if it can be useful, but when I try to make a transaction to the contract to give it some funds, but I get the following error:

VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Do you know what could be the problem? Why even if the method is correctly called it doesn't update the mapping structure?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here there is a transaction receipt form the javscript console log:
[image]

I also tried adding the following function to the solidity contract:

```
function getFilesCount() public view returns (uint256) {
    return filesList[msg.sender].length;
}
```

But when I call it from javascript I get always `0`.

Comment: Can you retrieve the transaction receipt? There's an error reported in ganache repo https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/2164. It might be that ganache doesn't display mappings yet.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael for your answer, I've added a screenshot of the receipt, can it be useful?

Comment: @Ismael as you can see in the "update" section of the question I've tried adding a function to retrieve the amount of elements in the selected item's array of the mapping but I still get 0, so I don't think the problem is Ganache

Comment: The receipt's status is true so the transaction was successful. How are you making the call to getFilesCount? The code is fine and it should work, so either ganache has a bug, used a wrong contract address, deployed a different contract, call to getFilesCount isn't correct.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for replying. As 3DLures stated in the answer below it can be a Ganache bug or something like that. I'll try creating a brand new environment/workspace with ganache and truffle with react. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying the Solidity code on my local environment running go-ethereum, it worked just fine.
It may sound dumb but after you altered the smart contract code and re-deployed it, did you add files to the storage? Because it's a new smart contract, new address, new storage.
Myself, I got rid of Ganache because it was acting different that the production network (go-ethereum)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Yes, I tried adding files to the storage but nothing changed. I'll try creating a completely new environment and workspace with Ganache and try it again. Thank you for trying my contract in your network, I was getting crazy.

Comment: Have you tried also the getFiles() method? I gave up to Ganache and switched to the Ropsten testnet but nothing changed...

Comment: Yes, I did call `getFilesCount()` and the count was correct. Are you using exactly the same code you posted above?

Comment: Yes, I am. It looks very strange, now I'll try restructuring the entire app, maybe something is going wrong behind the scenes with react and web3 js.